# How can get image path from my image helper that doesn't work

Tags: reactjs

I try to create a react application with this tree folder:

[image]

Now i create this helpers:

```
export const imagePath = (path) => {
      return `./assets/${path}` 
}
```

And simply to import on my components like this

```
import { imagePath } from './helpers';

<img className="h-6 w-6 rounded-full object-cover" src={imagePath('assets/img/profile.png')} alt="profile"></img>
```

But this doesn't work...why? What's wrong? How to get my assests path and import into components?
Thanks to everyone who wants to respond.
Marco.

Comment: Are you getting an error? the final path will be  `./assets/assets/img/profile.png` according to your setup. Is that intended?

Comment: Have you tried logging the "path" that gets passed to the helper? It seems to me that you are calling ```'./assets/assets/img...'```

Comment: Sorry, i paste an old code...actually is src={imagePath('img/profile.png')} but image don't show....the path is http://localhost:3000/assets/img/profile.png

Comment: 1. Did you create that on top of react-create-app?
2. does that start working if you copy the "profile.png" file to public/assets/img?

Comment: @WojciechDynus yes into public / assets / img works..but in my case the assets folder it's in src folder...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 3 options:

1. I don't recommend that because in theory on your server you should only have content from your "Public" directory and this might work with single-page applications only actually:

change your helper method to navigate to your src directory:
export const imagePath = (path) => {
      return `../src/assets/${path}` 
}

2. try getting the images using require method. So instead of using your imagePath you should try something like that:

Make sure to have the path relative to your img component. And make sure you have a file-loader in your webpack configuration

3. copy the files from assets to your public directory using webpack plugin like this https://github.com/webpack-contrib/copy-webpack-plugin

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest you to use `require` instead.

```
export const imagePath = (path) => {
   return require(`./assets/${path}`); 
}
```

Then inside your render:

```
src={imagePath('img/profile.png')}
```

**Note**: Keep in mind that this helper has to be in the same directory as `./assets`.